# how to stream a html mp3 using http server

Tags: html

i'm trying to make an http server with java that have an html as a response. And in the html file, i want to put a mp3 file and i want to stream it. But when i launch the code, the mp3 to stream doesn't appears in the browser. so i can't stream it!
so someone can help me to do that?..
p.s : i'm a beginner.
thanks
here is a part of my code:

```
  static final File WEB_ROOT = new File(".");
  static final String DEFAULT_FILE = "pg.html";
  File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, fileRequested);
  int fileLength = (int)file.length();
  String content = getContentType(fileRequested);
  if (method.equals("GET"))
  {
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    //create byte array to store file data
    byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];

    try
    {
      fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
      fileIn.read(fileData);
    }
    finally
    {`enter code here`
      close(fileIn); 
    }
```

and the pg.html contains  src="song1.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

Transmitting an HTML file and streaming an mp3 file are different. Your code is sending the html to the client, but it would be helpful to share the source of the html itself.

Currently, using html5, a simple audio control html entity would be the [best option](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/streaming-audio-and-video-with-html-5).

You should try it first with an mp3 file from another server (some public content).

Now when you are trying to stream your own local mp3 file, the browser will connect to your server and request "song1.mp3".

Using chrome/firefox developer tools you should be able to see your browser request the mp3 file when you first request the html file.

Comment: ok, i fixed it, i forget to put <audio controls> in my html file. ^^